# C# simple computation

Tags: c#, addition

Hi i'm making an simple c# computation sample Label1.Text = textBox1.Text + textbox2.Text i'm having a  problem when i try to input 88.5 or 80.3 and compute my program is keep crashing a getting errors.i already convert the text to Int and here's my code:

```
 int i;
 i = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
 Label1.Text= i.ToString();
```

But it's working if i insert 88 and 80 . i know i miss something on this.anyone can help me? thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to convert "88.5" into an *integer*. It's not an integer, is it?

I suggest you use `decimal` instead - and use `TryParse` so that you can handle invalid user input without resorting to exceptions.

```
decimal input1, input2;
if (decimal.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out input1) &&
    decimal.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out input2))
{
    Label1.Text = (input1 + input2).ToString();
}
else
{
    Label1.Text = "Invalid input";
}
```

Comment: @Jay: But do you understand *why* it works, and the problems of your original code?

Comment: yeah sir. Because i only use Integer not decimal

Comment: @JonSkeet Sir what if i want to multiply output1 to .20

Comment: @Jay: And don't forget to use *TryParse* ;)

Comment: @JonSkeet sir i use this code decimal ans = (output1 * .20) + (output2 * .20); but i get an error.

Comment: @Jay: "I get an error" is *never* enough information. What error? At compile time, or execution time? Do you understand why you're getting the error?